# How to restrict CPU load of FFmpeg call?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resources, cpu, video-editing

As described [here](https://superuser.com/a/100290), for example, I'm using FFmpeg to check video file integrity like this:

```
ffmpeg -v error -i input.mp4 -f null -
```

Since I plan to run this in the background, I want to limit the CPU load. I already tried `-threads 1`, `-filter_threads 1`, `-filter_complex_threads 1`. Nothing helps and FFmpeg still uses as many cores as it can get. Which parameter am I overlooking?

Comment: Are you actually parsing the log for possible error messages?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can limit this via FFmpeg but if you are using a Linux operating system you can use the `nice` command to control the CPU priority. It will still use maximum available CPU but will deprioritise the `ffmpeg` command if you set a higher `nice` value.

You can run a command like this:

```
nice -n 10 ffmpeg -v error -i input.mp4 -f null -
```

See more about nice settings here if you are not familiar: https://www.nixtutor.com/linux/changing-priority-on-linux-processes/

Bear in mind that if you are trying to do this at scale or on a server you might be better off with some kind of queue system and multi-server setup. Video processing is generally computationally expensive and you are best dedicating a whole machine to each task rather than trying to run several tasks at once on the same machine.